# How make a website monitorable?

Tags: php, monitor, zabbix

How to make a website build in PHP monitorable using monitoring agents like Zabbix?

I have built a website using a Website and now the client tells me that he wants it to be monitorable. He even told me about the software he is going to use to minitor it, I just dont know how to make it possible. I would'nt like to focus on the solution he is going to use, I wanted to keep the solution abstract. Have been reserarching and found something about CIM (Common Information Model), but nothing clear yet. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially do many things with zabbix, currently one of my client uses Zabbix to monitor over 500 virtual machines.

**Step 1:** Install zabbix server

**Step 2:** Install zabbix client on your php machine [zabbix server/client installation link](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/installation/install_from_packages)

**Step 3:** Configure host in zabbix sever (you can use [zabbix-UI](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/hosts/host))

That's it, you can see that Zabbix will start monitor your server(s)

Now, What zabbix can monitor:

- CPU utilization
- Memory usage
- Network In/Out
- Disk usage and many other

You can easily get the [Templates](https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/tree/master/php-fpm) for PHP to start basic monitoring

Other than that they have

- [Graphs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/visualisation/graphs/custom): You can use built-in or custom or own
- [Screen](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/visualisation/screens): You can segregate all your relative server to see at one
  place
- [Triggers](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/triggers/expression): You can create a alarms on uncertain usage (e.g. you disk is
  90% full or CPU utilization reached 70%, you can configure alerts
  based on criticality like disaster, high, medium, information..etc)
- It can even add host automatically by [Auto-discovery](http://harshalbulsara.wix.com/harshalbulsara#!Zabbix-AutoRegistration/mux7q/565d6a690cf211cbf010bd48)

Answer (score 1):

The response is here.
[Zabbix Doc](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring)
Basically you can simulate with zabbix, the "clicks" on your website and get data like: response time, response code, download time/speed and other...